# Soft assertion is not working in Pytest when used in a framework

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, assertion

I have developed a framework on Selenium Python with Page Object Model, in which the driver is passes to different pages through constructor. For validation, I am using soft assertion that should execute till the end even if encountering failures. But, here I am facing the issue in the soft assertion where the code execution is getting stopped after encountering the first failure.

Here is the code for constructor which is defined for each page:

```
class Demo(BaseClass, softest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, driver, **kwds):
        self.driver = driver
        super().__init__(**kwds)
```

The below is the syntax used for soft assertion in order to validate:

```
self.soft_assert(self.assertEqual, actual, expected)
```

Comment: I don't see where you've defined `soft_assert`. Add a stack trace so that we can help debug your issue. For Python/Selenium/pytest tests, you may want to try a framework with built-in soft assertions. Here's an example of a test that uses that: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_deferred_asserts.py

Comment: `import softest
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from Utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class Demo(BaseClass, softest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, driver, **kwds):
        self.driver = driver
        super().__init__(**kwds)`

Comment: According to https://pypi.org/project/softest/ you need to call `self.assert_all()` before the end of your test to process those assertions. Is that the issue you're having, or are you seeing an error?